# How to toggle custom video-js component visibility on user inactivity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js, videojs-overlay

I'm using VideoJS with react and have created a Custom title-bar component using `videojs-overlay`. What I want is, when the user is inactive(mouse not moving), that title bar should fade out and fade in as the user moves the mouse. This is done in the `ControlBar` component, but for custom components how to do is not clear.

```
var TitleBar = videojs.extend(Component, {
    constructor: function () {
        // It is important to invoke the superclass before anything else,
        // to get all the features of components out of the box!
        Button.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    // The `createEl` function of a component creates its DOM element.
    createEl: function () {
        return videojs.dom.createEl('div', {
            //want to toggle show/hide on user activity here with CSS classes
            className: `vjs-title-bar`,
            alt: 'Title Bar',
            innerHTML: `
            <div class="back-btn" >
                <button onclick="alert(1234)" >
                    <span>
                        <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-left"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            `,
        });
    },
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have no exp with react, but try this: аfter

```
Button.apply(this, arguments);
```

add something like:

```
this.on(this.player(), ["useractive", "userinactive"], this.showHide);
```

then add this func to component:

```
showHide: function(ev) {
    if (ev.type === 'userinactive') {
        this.hide() //hide immediately! 
        //if you want animation, add class to your css and do this.addClass("myHideClass")
    } else {
        this.show();
    }
}
```